# getting Cannot read property '0' of undefined when i click google map marker?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I am getting error when i click google map marker how to solve this problem i have enclosed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cLADs/135/ .when i click button it should pass id value based on marker click some one help me out to move forward.

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
    ['0', 'Madivala', 12.914494, 77.560381, 'car','as12'],
    ['1', 'Majestic', 12.961229, 77.559281, 'third','as13'],
    ['2', 'Ecity', 12.92489905, 77.56070772, 'car','as14'],
    ['3', 'Jp nagar', 12.91660662, 77.52047465, 'second','as15']
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9667,77.5667);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
    var category = marker[4];
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[1];
    var fullContent = marker.slice(1,6).join();

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        map: map
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, fullContent) {
        return function () {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            infowindow.setContent(fullContent);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(15);
            
            ///////

  // Set CSS for the control border.
  var controlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.innerHTML = 'Center Map';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  // Setup the click event listeners: simply set the map to Chicago.
  controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //Do Whatever you want here
  });
  controlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(controlDiv);         
            ///////
        }
    })(marker1, fullContent));
}

/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */

filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

// Init map
initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">Please select category</option>
    <option value="second">second</option>
    <option value="car">car</option>
    <option value="third">third</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you print our your `i` in your listener, you will realized it always to be 4. Basically, the listener does not remember the number `i`, since it is a globe variable.

Look at the [Google Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-closure), they called a function and setup the info window inside.(so that it is `i` independent) You might do the same too.

Another solution is to store the value `i` as a tag to the marker, so that you can retrieve it from the marker object.